# How to select non-continuous columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I'd like to pull all rows, with columns 71, 73, and 101 to 150 (or the last column).

I tried the following:

```
df.iloc[:, [71, 73, 101: ]]
```

Then I get the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-230-3e63bc939d38>", line 1
    corr = df_next.iloc[:, [70, 72, 101:150]].corr()
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm not sure what the correct syntax is.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with `numpy`

```
df.iloc[:, np.r_[71, 73, 101:150]]
```

Comment: @SayandipDuttaS you sure ?

Comment: @SayandipDutta ah , forget add 150 ~

Answer (score 1):

You can use unpacking with `range`:

```
df.iloc[:, [71, 73,*range(101,df.shape[1])]]
```